# Base64: how to encode / decode the entire HTML code of a page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, phantomjs, base64

i'm trying to encode a page:

```
btoa(document.querySelector('html').innerHTML)
```

But it doesn't work with such data, does anyone know, how it can be done?

Comment: do you want to encode the page text only??

Comment: That is text only...What I think @pradeep1991singh meant is, do you want to include CSS, Images, etc. etc.

Comment: Also why? This seems kinda pointless

Comment: If want to verify html then you can simply use `JSON.stringify` before `btoa` and `JSON.parse` after `atob`.

Comment: If you only need to detect changes, isn't the JSON stringify enough? What does base64 encoding give you?

Comment: base64 encoding would be huge and the time load such monster outweighs any benefits it may offer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unicode characters can be reason of this. Try to use this example from mozilla site (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa):

```
function utoa(str) {
    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
}

function atou(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(str)));
}

// Usage:
utoa('✓ à la mode'); // 4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU=
atou('4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU='); // "✓ à la mode"

utoa('I \u2661 Unicode!'); // SSDimaEgVW5pY29kZSE=
atou('SSDimaEgVW5pY29kZSE='); // "I ♡ Unicode!"
```